# Runtime error dealing with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

The below code runs perfectly fine in eclipse but when I run it on different IDE that I use for my homework, it throws a runtime error message. Any thoughts or ideas why? Thanks.

```
final int NUM_VALS = 4;
  int[] courseGrades = new int[NUM_VALS];
  int i = 0;

  courseGrades[0] = 7;
  courseGrades[1] = 9;
  courseGrades[2] = 11;
  courseGrades[3] = 10;

  for (i = 0; i < NUM_VALS; i++) {
      System.out.print(courseGrades[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  for (i = NUM_VALS -1; i < NUM_VALS; i--) {
      System.out.print(courseGrades[i] + " ");
  }
  return;
```

This is the output:

7 9 11 10

10 11 9 7

Comment: `(i = NUM_VALS -1; i < NUM_VALS; i--) ` should be `(i = NUM_VALS -1; i >= 0; i--) `

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: do you get a run-time error or incorrect results?

Comment: @Mureinik     " Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.)."

Comment: i get correct results while running in eclipse but a runtime error when i submit on m homework website

Comment: You will find that you're getting an Exception, most likely array index out of bounds exception, even if the output up until that point is correct.

Comment: i edited the output. The program is supposed to print the output i wrote above and mine does that.

Comment: @vikingsteve how would i fix that?

Comment: Read the first comment from Lashane or the answer from Willam B....

Comment: @Joe I know what a runtime error is. I'm asking for the stacktrace you're getting to be able to intelligently answer this question.

Comment: @Mureinik java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second `for` loop is an infinite loop - you start with a value smaller than `NUM_VALS` and then just continue decreasing it (well, at least it theoretically is - as you noticed, it fails on an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` eventually). In short, you end condition is wrong - the loop should iterate as long as `i` is non-negative:

```
for (i = NUM_VALS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print(courseGrades[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you second for loop should be:

```
  for (i = NUM_VALS -1; i >=0; i--) {...
```